# How can I reduce width the shadow behind in BarChart Value

Tags: vue.js, echarts, element-ui

I'm using BarChart ( echarts )

How can I reduce width the shadow behind in BarChart Value ?

[image: images]

Comment: The default bar chart does not have shadow. Can you provide some code for your case?

Comment: This is the BarChart i use : https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/blob/master/src/views/dashboard/admin/components/BarChart.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reduce [barCategoryGap](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barCategoryGap), it will help to compress the space between bars.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

var option = {
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: [1, 6, 6, 2, 8, 7, 2, 4],
    barCategoryGap: '10%' // <--------- here
  }],
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but I encountered a different problem. I want to change the width of the values on the x axis, how can I do it ?

Comment: Try to change it with [barWidth](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.barWidth)

Comment: when i tried, values are intertwined, titles( values on the XAxis) do not shift.

Comment: Could you publish code with the jsfiddle? Without it is very hard to guess where mistake.

Comment: Hi, https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/blob/master/src/views/dashboard/admin/components/BarChart.vue

Comment: This is not what I asked you to do but OK, [this is example](https://jsfiddle.net/creadone/qd5kvaxo/), please set option that cause an error and show to me.

Comment: I want to increase title bar length (XAxis). https://imgur.com/Fv5oO48

Comment: This? https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.width

Comment: I understand each you word and all of words together but not  understand desired result ) Could you describe final result?

Comment: Some Labels do not appear. https://imgur.com/qV1PyiR

Comment: Echarts can control labels to prevent intersection. Sorry, you comment is not relevant to the question. You need to learn Echarts https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html